# How to turn off completion suggesitons in OS X (NSTextFiled & NSTextView)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield, nstextview

How do I turn off the auto-suggest text that pops up in my `NSTextField` (or `NSTextView`)? It looks like this:

[image]

(This can be brought up manually by pressing <kbd>esc</kbd>)

Answer (score 3):

**For `NSTextField`**

Implement the `delegate` method : `- control:textView:completions:forPartialWordRange:indexOfSelectedItem:` so that it returns null:

```
-(NSArray *)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView completions:(NSArray *)words forPartialWordRange:(NSRange)charRange indexOfSelectedItem:(NSInteger *)index{
    return nil;
}
```

**For `NSTextView`**

Do the same, but with the following method; `- textView:completions:forPartialWordRange:indexOfSelectedItem:`

source: http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2008/Oct/msg02042.html